# Display all JSON data from NSDictionary to UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am fairly new to iOS development, been at it for 2 years or so. I have developed an app for my Litecoin mining pool that is able to pull data from the API url in JSON format. I am able to get individual variables from JSON, but I want to display all of the data from the "workers" block into a UITableView. Here is an example of the JSON:

{"username":"n00bminer","balance":"0","total_hashrate":"1429","payout_history":"0.71828344","round_shares":"96908","workers":
{

**"n00bminer.1":{"hashrate":"998","last_share_timestamp":"1392906308","accepted_shares":"84755","stale_shares":"913"},
"n00bminer.cpu":
{"hashrate":"0","accepted_shares":"7891","stale_shares":"11"},
"n00bminer.2":{"hashrate":"431","last_share_timestamp":"1392906300","accepted_shares":"13285","stale_shares":"118"}**

}}

(bolded is the part that I need) Live data: http://www.ielitepool.com/api.php?api_key=9d9be4bd59eb8de59f1cac981099c43e866b0cc07a5555dd922c9efc08ac31a1

I request this using:

```
    NSData* apiData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"api_url"]]
                        ];
    NSDictionary* json = nil;
    if (apiData) {
        json = [NSJSONSerialization
                JSONObjectWithData:apiData
                options:kNilOptions
                error:nil];
    }
```

and get individual variables using:

```
float total_hashrate = [[json valueForKey:@"total_hashrate"] floatValue];
```

How can I get all of the workers, as well as their stats in one UITableView. For example, I don't want the worker name to only display, then have it lead to another UITableViewController, but rather the name and then the stats underneath (hashrate, accepted_shares, etc.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is there anything you have tried yet to display the list of workers in the table view? If you can share more code related to the table view design or delegate, you may get some more valuable answers.

Comment: Maybe should consider converting the JSON to classes that support the NSCoding protocol. http://github.com/ontometrics/JSONCoding.git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will print worker's information:

```
[json[@"workers"] enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSDictionary *obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"worker = %@  : hashrate = %f last_share_timestamp = %f",
          key, [obj[@"hashrate"] floatValue], [obj[@"last_share_timestamp"] floatValue] );
}];
```

If you will have troubles displaying info in table, please create separate question with code sample.

Comment: Was it useful for you?

Comment: Yes! This is awesome! How can I get this into a UITableView? The table view is called declared by IBOutlet UITableView* workerTable;

Comment: Ok, I will ask a different question. Thank you for the help, this pointed me in the right direction.